# youtube crashing on slackware 14.0

Tags: flash, firefox, youtube, slackware

Some video will play for a bit, then it simply says "an error occured, please try again later".

I'm using firefox 15, adobe flashplayer 11.  I didn't seem to have this problem on Slackware 13.37.

I've tried installing the SlackBuild of flashplayer as well as just copying the .so from the download to plugins.  I've also tried different browsers.

Chrome will play the video with no audio out (I have an HDMI out configured... aplay is able to play sounds through the HDMI and I'm able to watch movies in VLC with no problem).

If I use chrome, this is the output in bash when I fire up youtube:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:7431:(snd_pcm_set_params) Rate doesn't match (requested 44100Hz, get 0Hz)
ALSA lib pcm.c:7442:(snd_pcm_set_params) Unable to set period time 23219 for PLAYBACK: Invalid argument
```

If I do:

```
aplay -D plughw:1.3 /usr/share/sounds/pop.wav
```

I get a sound, no problem (this is my HDMI card)

If I just do:

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/pop.wav
```

Then I get "Channels count non available"

EDIT: ok, more weirdness.  When I play VLC and youtube video simultaneously, youtube no longer crashes.  Instead, the VLC plays audio through HDMI, while the youtube plays audio through the laptop speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Flash not very good work in Linux+Firefox.
You may enable html5 mode in Youtube preferences
http://www.youtube.com/html5

I too using Slackware and not have problem with FF+html5 player, but my version of FF is 22

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up an ~/.asoundrc?

```
pcm.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
}

ctl.!default {
  type hw
  card 1
}
```

What channels does 'alsamixer' show when you run it?